# Fill column values in dataframe with current subdirectory name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to fill the column value in a dataframe with current sub-directory name:

current directory: home/user/Desktop/files/NY

dataframe:

```
Location :
NaN
NaN 
NaN
```

I would like the columns values to be filled with the current subdirectory name as below:

```
Location :
NY 
NY
NY
```

Could someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get current working directory:

```py
import os
curr_dir = os.getcwd().split('\\')[-1]
```

To change dataframe values:
`df["Location"] = curr_dir`

`os.getcwd()` gets your current working directory, e.g home/user/Desktop/files/NY. Splot by "\" to get different folders, and take the last element in list for current folder

Or, as suggested in comments:
`curr_dir = os.path.basename(os.getcwd())` to get it directly

Comment: Alternatively you can use `os.path.basename(os.getcwd())` for the same result.

Comment: @AlwaysRightNeverLeft absolutely. Thank you